# @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm doing a relativity simple implementation of Hilt.  I've set it up and I can't seem to get around this error:

[Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

```
@dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context is injected at
      com.greendotcorp.core.managers.featurecontrol.app.FeatureControlManager(context, …)
  com.greendotcorp.core.managers.featurecontrol.app.FeatureControlManager is injected at
      com.greendotcorp.core.features.dashboard.GridDashboardFragment.featureControlManager
  com.greendotcorp.core.features.dashboard.GridDashboardFragment is injected at
      
  com.greendotcorp.core.utils_theme.ViewModelDependencyInjector.inject
```

Here is my code:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ViewModelInjectorModule::class])
interface ViewModelDependencyInjector {
    fun inject(fragment: GridDashboardFragment)
}

@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
@Module
object DashboardModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideFeatureComponentManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : FeatureControlManager {
    return FeatureControlManager.getInstance(context)
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class GridDashboardFragment : BaseDetailFragment() {

   @Inject lateinit var featureControlManager: FeatureControlManager
}
```

I'm new to Hilt - any ideas?

Comment: Kristy, have you managed to find a solution, this problem is driving me insane

Comment: Same here - it would be nice if you can share your solution if you have found any

Comment: I was attempting to use activity context but application context worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is happening because in InstallIn() you are passing a fragment component and you are annotating your dependency with singleton , as far as i know that singleton can be applied to ApplicationComponent , so try to change @Singleton annotation to @FragmentScoped Annotation

```
@Provides  
@Singleton --> to @FragmentScoped
fun provideFeatureComponentManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : FeatureControlManager {
    return FeatureControlManager.getInstance(context)
}
```