# android(Hilt + Dagger2): provide context in domain module

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a multi-module app where the app module depends on feature modules. I am trying to provide a dataStore object in my domain module but I require a context for this. However, Dagger can not provide this without an @Provides method. In the app module, I am using hilt and in my feature modules, I am using dagger.

I create a dataStore variable in the context:

```
val Context.dataStore by dataStore(....)
```

then in my domain module

```
@Module
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStore(context: Context): DataStore<...> = 
               context.dataStore 
}
```

and recieve the following:

```
Context cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method
```

I tried using @BindInstance

I tried using @ApplicationContext but receive the following error from my feature module: 'dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext' could not be resolved.
I think this is because my feature modules are set up to use Dagger2 which this annotation is not included

```
Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.fitness.remote.di.OnboardingDomainModule
      => element (METHOD): provideUserPreferencesDataStore(android.content.Context)
      => element (PARAMETER): context
      => annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
      => type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
```

Also, my app module depends on my feature modules so the following article will not work unless I am misunderstanding it

- https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module
- https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-multi-module#dagger-dfm

Additional Info:
The only reason I am using Dagger in my feature modules is so I can process custom annotations for multi-binding. If there is a way Hilt can provide this. then I believe this could also solve the problem above cause then I would be able to access the SingletonComponent from my feature modules where the context is currently provided

Answer (score 0):

Dagger hilt is able to provide the application context, you just have to mark your context parameter in the function as follows:

```
@ApplicationContext context : Context
```

Your code will then become:

```
@Module
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStore<...> = 
           context.dataStore 
}
```

Comment: With this method, I am getting the following error from my feature module: 'dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext' could not be resolved. I think this is because my feature modules are setup to use Dagger2 which this annotation is not included

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63421980/9015853

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide context when using Dagger2.

1. Add a bind function in a module of the application component and define a qualifier to distinguish from other contexts

   ```
   @Module
   interface ContextModule {
       @Binds
       @AppContext
       fun bindApplicationContext(application: Application): Context
   }

   @Qualifier
   @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
   annotation class AppContext
   ```
2. Add the application instance into the dependency graph with `@BindsInstance`

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Component(
       modules = [
           ContextModule::class,
           // other modules
       ]
   )
   interface AppComponent {
       @Component.Builder
       interface Builder {
           fun bindApplication(@BindsInstance application: Application): Builder
           fun build(): AppComponent
       }

       // define app component's function
   }
   ```
3. Add @AppContext qualifier to the parameter

   ```
    @Module
    class DomainModule {

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideDataStore(@AppContext context: Context): DataStore<...> = 
               context.dataStore 
    }
   ```

If you only provide the application context, then you don't have to define the qualifier.

Comment: Hilt is used in the app module and dagger is used in the feature modules. So defining a dagger component cant be done in the app module and the application context qualifier can not be processed in the feature module

Comment: @onStackOverflowListener https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module
this might be helpful.

Comment: I did read this before but what confused me in the example is that there is an App module and a separate Login feature module. It suggests creating an @EntryPoint interface in the app module and creating a component in the feature module that depends on that interface. Isn't this creating a circular dependency because the only way to include that module is to include the app in the feature module

Comment: Unless in the example the feature module depends on the app module

Comment: @onStackOverflowListener would you try providing the data store in the app module? it would work as the app module depends on feature modules

Comment: No this won't work either  (I have tried this) because the dataStore is accessed via use cases in the domain module. The app module depends on the feature module which depends on the domain module. Dagger still would not be able to process this. I am trying out your solution above but using hilts custom components

Answer (score 0):

I don't think domain module should contain android related classes like Context, you should abstract it by a repository class that contains the code for Datastore, and the classes for repository and Datastore should exist in your features modules.

Comment: Why shouldn't it exist in a module?

Comment: Also, the code for accessing the data store is handled in a UserPreferencesManager which (unless I am wrong) is what you're suggesting with the repository. But regardless the data store needs to be injected and for this it needs a context

Comment: Yes, if you're using UserPreferencesManager as an abstraction then you're fine but in which module does it exist?